# Better way to call a function only once in a code snippet in c++ when we don't care about return value?

Tags: c++

Just curious if it is syntactically possible to do something like this:

```
static (void) someFunc();
```

instead of, say,

```
static bla = someFunc();
```

so as to invoke `someFunc` only once when we go through that section of code? The (void) snippet doesn't compile by the way.

Comment: does just going `someFunc();` not work?

Comment: @corsiKa The point is having the function be executed only once.

Comment: You could have a static bool `functionCalled`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `static` is intended only to work with value initialization.

To document that you aren't interested in the return value, you could write:

```
static int unused = (someFunc(), void(), 0);
```

The `void()` is to prevent a comma operator being called; you could also write `(void(someFunc()), 0)` using a functional cast.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it's there in case the return type of `someFunc` has a comma operator defined.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by explaining that. And are you not concerned that it doesn't compile because of it?  Maybe you want `((void)someFunc(), 0)` or `(someFunc(),(void)0,0)`

Comment: Yeah, I could be wrong but that syntax doesn't look valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's always `pthread_once`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_once.html

Comment: That may be overkill, calling it in the initializer of a static variable ensures it happens once, and is thread-safe too (with a C++11 compiler, or decent C++03 compilers such as GCC or Clang).

Answer (score 0):

Other than moving the guard *inside* the function, I don't see how that would be possible.